# how to Calculate if a circle can include the other circles?

Tags: c

I want to create a red circle that can contain the other circles, if i have the other circles radius and know the quantity. How can I calculate the red big circle radius by code. the circles always Tangent。 How do I know what is the smallest radius red circle that can do this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the case of the right-hand diagram it is simple: the sum of the two radii.

Comment: This is a math problem, not a coding problem. Try to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: tensorflow can do this

Comment: @sunne "if i have the other circles radius and know the quantity." --> do you also have their origins  (their centers' x,y coordinates)?